# Pause then Resume Pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to make it so this script pauses when when I press "esc" and then resumes when I press "home". It's like 90% there but when I pause the script, the "a" button still functions as if the script is not paused. I tried putting sleep in other places of this script but this causes extreme lag due to the threads. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode

mouse = Controller()


def exit_program():
    def on_press(key):

        if key == KeyCode.from_char('a'):
            mouse.press(Button.right), mouse.release(Button.right)

        if str(key) == 'Key.esc':
            main.status = 'pause'
            print("Paused")

        if str(key) == 'Key.home':
            main.status = 'run'
            print("Resume")
        elif str(key) == 'Key.end':
            main.status = 'exit'
            print("Exit")
            exit()

    listener = keyboard.Listener(
        supress=True,
        on_press=on_press)
    listener.start()


def main():
    main.status = 'run'

    while True:
        print('running')
        time.sleep(1)

        while main.status == 'pause':
            time.sleep(1)

        if main.status == 'exit':
            print('Main program closing')
            break


Thread(target=main).start()
Thread(target=exit_program).start()
```

Comment: inside `on_press` you could run some code in `if main.status != 'pause':`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `main.status` in `on_press`. You should check for "a" and "esc" only if paused, and "home" only if running.

However, a much cleaner way to accomplish this would be to use a proper multithreaded communication primitive. You could use a `threading.Event` that you set to pause and clear to resume, or a `queue.queue` to send messages from the key press handler to main (an event queue). These would let you get rid of the sleep calls entirely.

Comment: Thanks dude I have to learn more about threads I appreciate the help.